# Cannot find R dependencies even though they are there

Tags: python, r, command-line

I have a script that requires activation of a virtual environment:

```
source activate metagenomics
```

after which R is used to plot some data

However, when I run the script, I get an error saying:

```
ERROR: The following R libraries are missing
dplyr
getopt
ggplot2
gsubfn
gplots
```

I have manually checked to see that the version of R does have these dependencies.

Not sure if this is related but when I load the package gplots in R, it is accompanied by a message: `attaching package: gplots`

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Are you assuming that the python venv is supposed to contain your R libraries? I wonder how the two are related ... is it easy or even possible to blur the lines between the two concepts of py-venv and R library?

Comment: i dont really understand how R and py-venv may be related. But it's weird how the script runs into the error of not being able to find the R dependencies when I've manually been able to load these same libraries myself.

Comment: Using these packages in an interactive session but not in a script is commonly due to the use of a personal library (see `.libPaths()` and all questions relating to it), sometimes caused by the presence and contents of `~/.Rprofile`. This last file is not typically referenced for scripts, so if there is anything pertinent to libraries in there then that could be causing your problem.